# Using new Date().getTime() to show future dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, if-statement, time

Im trying to get a set of functions that will change the value of a selected post's date.

Im using an if else statement within an each function to change date values per post,
Changing value when date has expired is working but I cant seem to change the future date values. Not sure how to use new Date().getTime() to get the future date

Help would be much appreciated

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6QmRU/

Code below

```
 $('.post-title').each(function () {
  if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
    $(this).css({
        opacity: 0.5,
        border: '2px solid red'
    });
    $(this).find('.post-date-input').text('This has expired');
  }
  //Today
  else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() == new Date().getTime()){
    $(this).find('.post-date-input').text('This is today');
  }
  //Tommorow
  else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() == new Date().getTime() + 1){
    $(this).find('.post-date-input').text('This is tomorrow');
  }
});
```

Comment: getTime returns milliseconds from epoch, so you'd be really lucky if the date right now would ever match the date on your posts, as the likelyhood of that is almost like winning the lottery. You have to reset the Date objects to zero time (00:00) and compare days only. Also note that you have severaly syntax errors showing up in the console.

Comment: Please, use *variables* instead evaluating/writing `new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime()`, `new Date().getTime()` and `$(this).find('.post-date-input').text(…)` thrice.

Comment: @adeneo so the current way im doing it is incorrect? Could you point me in the direction of the best method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Area

```
else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() == new Date().getTime());
                                                                          ^

else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() == new Date().getTime() + 1);
                                                                              ^
```

You have couple of missplaceed `;`, just remove them

```
$('.post-title').each(function () {
    console.log(new Date($(this).data('date')))
    if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 0.5,
            border: '2px solid red'
        });
        $(this).find('.post-date-input').text('This has expired');
    }
    //Today
    else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() == new Date().getTime()) {
        $(this).find('.post-date-input').text('This is today');
    }
    //Tommorow
    else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() == (new Date().getTime() + 1)) {
        $(this).find('.post-date-input').text('This is today');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/W6tEv/1/)